# How to notify JMS listener for 'no objects' message

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I need to sync some 'car' repositories (managed by different slave-servers) to one repository (managed by one master-server).

For that matter I'm using ActiveMQ.
I've defined a queue (master.car.queue) which the master will listen to and all slaves will post there their car repository (every 5 minutes).

I have a scenario where one slave has one car in its repository - so it publishes a corresponding message. 
Couple of minutes later, this car is sold - so this slave's repository is empty now - how should it notify that to the master?

I thought of the following options:

1) Create another queue for that use-case.

2) Use the same master.car.queue - but send a new message type or set a some property on that message.

What is the best practice for this use-case?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your queue consumer design and if it is able to treat these use cases and if from business point of view what you do with messages.
For example if received messages are just injected un a database you can create 2 consumers (one to insert and one to update or remove) for 2 queues for these 2 use cases and use your first proposition or use 1 queue and use a Message Router from the EIP patterns as messages receiver to route to differents consumers